# PrincipalPermission vs Authorize Attribute?

Tags: c#, attributes, authorize-attribute, principalpermission

Can anybody explain to me the differences and use cases of these two attributes? I am quite confused since they behave similarly.

I know that the [Authorize] hooks into the ASP.NET application life cycle and run before the request reach to the Controller/Action. How about the PrincipalPermission?

```
[PrincipalPermission(SecurityAction.Demand, Role="Admin")]
```

And

```
[Authorize(Roles="Admin")]
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`Authorize` attribute is used  to specifiy access restriction to a controller or action method. In other words, you can grant or deny users/roles access to visit individual pages or URLs within a site.

When you authenticate a user within an ASP.NET application, the authenticated user's identity will be automatically flowed throughout that user's request on the server.

You can use this identity information on business classes through `PrincipalPermission` attribute. With `PrincipalPermission` you can authorize a user's capabilities. For instance, you can prevent users from instantiating a class or accessing a method on your business classes.

This makes it easy to add clean security authorization rules to your business and data layers.

```
using System;
using System.Security.Permissions;

[PrincipalPermission(SecurityAction.Demand, Authenticated = true)]
public class EmployeeManager
{
    [PrincipalPermission(SecurityAction.Demand, Role = "Manager")]
    public Employee LookupEmployee(int employeeID)
    {
       // todo
    }

    [PrincipalPermission(SecurityAction.Demand, Role = "HR")]
    public void AddEmployee(Employee e)
    {
       // todo
    }
}
```

For instance, using the `PrincipalPermission` attribute,

- `EmployeeManager` class can only be instantiated by authorized users.
- `LookupEmployee` method can only be accesssed by users with `Manager` role.

**References**

[Adding Authorization Rules to Business and Data Layers](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/Tip_2F00_Trick_3A00_-Adding-Authorization-Rules-to-Business-and-Data-Layers-using-PrincipalPermissionAttributes)

[ASP.NET 2.0 Security Best Practices](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/430598)

Comment: Are you saying that the PrinciplePermission attribute can be used outside of controllers/action methods, but the Authorize attribute cannot?

Comment: Also, the PrinciplePermission attribute seems to give you the capability to do things like actively Deny a particular role as well (Maybe our method should accept access by all users with role 'Employee' except those who also have role 'Temporary').

Comment: @EFO yes, according to MSDN you can only use Authorize attribute on controllers or action methods.